# slideDown incoming data in jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am new into jQuery AJAX, so I apologize if the question is too obvious.

I have 2 webforms in ASP.NET, one is to add data into database, the other is to show data in ul-li format.

So far I have succeed only the basic jQuery AJAX, whenever there is a new data, it is shown.

I want that whenever new data is added, it must be shown to the user as **slideDown** format.

**Note: I don't have any answer. The answer below did not help.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'WebForm1.aspx',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#Urunler").html("<li>" + data + "</li>");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        td
        {
            width: 200px;
            height: 30px;
            background: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


        <ul id="Urunler" runat="server">

        </ul>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("#Urunler").hide().html("<li>" + data + "</li>").slideDown();
```

Since your AJAX is on page-load, you can start with the UL hidden via CSS and remove that `.hide()`, either way.

Comment: Or for a more fancy effect, replace `.hide()` with `.slideUp()`.

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand -- Thought about that, but if the UL is empty at the start, won't make much difference.

Comment: True that, however the OP will need this after every submission of the form

Comment: Why every second, that doesn't make much sense?

Comment: That AJAX call is only going to run once.